# Random numbers with different probabilities

Tags: c++, random, probability

I need to randomly determine a yes or no outcome (kind of a coin flip) based on a probability that I can define (.25, .50, .75).

So for example, I want to randomly determine yes or no where yes has a 75% chance of being chosen. What are my options for this? Is there a C++ library I can use for this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can easily implement this using the `rand` function:

```
bool TrueFalse = (rand() % 100) < 75;
```

The `rand() % 100` will give you a random number between 0 and 100, and the probability of it being under 75 is, well, 75%. You can substitute the `75` for any probability you want.

Comment: +1, and don't forget to `srand()`

Comment: More or less equally probable...Suppose RAND_MAX is 32767; then for numbers 0..67, there is one more value available to be chosen at random than there is for 68..99.  Whether this matters depends on the context.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ah that's true.... let's see what we can do about that...

Comment: @user1229962 as Jonathan pointed out, the distribution is not perfectly distributed. You'll have to take into account when the number is close to `RAND_MAX` - IMO this is negligible though.

Comment: For my application if the probability is actually 75.01% it doesn't matter, as long as it's close. Thanks guys!

Comment: @user1229962 in that case, yes, that's fine.

Comment: I don't see why this deserves a downvote... but okay.

Comment: @user1229962 Please consider using the C++11 engines.

Comment: Use C++11 / TR1 <random>. Easier not a broken distribution.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore it deserves a down vote because it's bad. Not only is the whole srand/rand machinery awfully ugly designed, but also there's no way here to get probabilities of 12.5 etc.

Comment: @cooky451 what do you mean by srand/rand awfully designed? Also... sure there is, %1000, < 125...

Comment: @Luchian Grigore By awfully designed I mean that there is only one state for the whole application. This is so bad in so many ways, I have to wonder way anyone would even consider using that. And yes, % 1000 is a way, but what's the next step? 10000? 100000? Not good, that's most likely bigger than RAND_MAX. A real distribution is the way to go (as I already stated).

Comment: @cooky451 I totally agree that better options exist, but I still think this is still a valid alternative, especially for such a simple task. If I wanted a bool with 75% probability, I'd use `rand`...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I wouldn't. Who know where srand() gets called in a big application or which other functions use rand(). I don't want to share the state with the whole application. As for the 75%: That only where examples. He mentioned "kind of a coin flip", which implies that he will most likely need probabilities like 12.5% etc. This "algorithm" is just not suitable for the task.

Comment: @cooky451 also, your answer seems to only apply for C++11.

Comment: If RAND_MAX is 32767, the percentage of selected values less than 75 will be about 75.0518% theoretically (100 * (328*68 + 327 * 7) / 32768 = 75.0518); empirically, I measured 75.0564%. If RAND_MAX is 0x7FFFFFFF, the difference is much smaller (75.0008% empirically; 100*(21474837*48 + 21474836*27) / 2147483648 = 
75.00000056% theoretically). If you have the C99 minimally acceptable `rand()` function, there's a noticeable (bit still small and often insignificant) bias; if you have 32-bit RAND_MAX, the bias is usually negligible. But you must know what RAND_MAX is to make that judgement call.

Answer (score 9):

Check at the C++11 pseudo random number library.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Extensible_random_number_facility

```
std::random_device rd;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1, 100);
std::mt19937 engine(rd()); // Mersenne twister MT19937

int value=distribution(engine);
if(value > threshold) ...
```

like this, then say all above 75 is true, and all below is false, or whatever threshold you want

Unlike `rand` you can actually control the properties of the number generation, also I don't believe rand as used in other answers (using modulo) even presents a uniform distribution, which is bad.

Comment: Please use a real distribution, so I can vote you up.

Comment: @cooky451 surely if it is supposed to mimmic a coin toss uniform is the correct distribution?

Comment: But you're not emulating the coin flips (that would be taking 1 out 2 several times), you're doing all at once. The next step would be a probability of 12.5, how are you going to do that with an integer? Sure, you can then switch to a [1..1000] range, but still, a real distribution is the logical way to go.

Comment: Actually... Yes! this is better. if using modulo you get uniform distribution just when (threshold mod 2 = 0) because C++ RAND_MAX = 2^31 - 1. Or there are 2^31 possible values. (adding zero)
Example. rand() % 5 where (suposition) RAND_MAX = 16
*****
*****
*****
*[----]   <--- this is 4 spaces make impossible the uniform distr.
**p : probability**;
p(rand() % 4 == 0) = 4/16
p(rand() % 4 == 1) = 3/16
p(rand() % 4 == 2) = 3/16
p(rand() % 4 == 3) = 3/16
p(rand() % 4 == 4) = 3/16

Answer (score 3):

`std::random_device` or `boost::random` if `std::random_device` is not implemented by your C++ compiler, using a `boost::random` you can use `bernoulli_distribution` to generate a random `bool` value!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool yesOrNo(float probabilityOfYes) {
  return rand()%100 < (probabilityOfYes * 100);
}

int main() {
    srand((unsigned)time(0)); 
    cout<<yesOrNo(0.897);
}
```

if you call `yesOrNo(0.75)` it will return `true` 75% of the time.

Comment: since `probabilityOfYes` is of type `int`, it is identical to `yesOrNo(0)` and will return always `no`. (probably meant it to be a `float` or a `double`)

Comment: @amit that's right. I have edited the code.