# Modified random number generator

Tags: c++, math, random, probability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random numbers with different probabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885356/random-numbers-with-different-probabilities)

I have to write a function that will take a parameter `p = either 0.25 or 0.5 or 0.75` and return `yes / no` with `Probablity(yes) = p`. As I have uniform random number generator `rand()` my idea is

```
//representing yes -> '1' and no -> '0'
char myRandom(double d){
    char array[4];
    if (p(yes) == 0.25) strcpy(arr,"1000");
    if (p(yes) == 0.50) strcpy(arr,"1100");
    if (p(yes) == 0.75) strcpy(arr,"1110");
    return arr[rand(0,4)];
}
```

I know it is not efficient if there are much more probablities. But other than this is there any wrong in my idea? If there is then where?

Comment: You guys appear to be taking the same course.

Comment: did you intend `if (p == 0.25)` etc?

Comment: One error is that your array is not big enough because strcpy copies a trailing null byte. Up the size to 5, or use memcpy.